# Custom wicket from validator message from database

Tags: java, wicket

I have my own wicket(1.5.x) Custom String loader loaded on appliation startup which fetches data from a dictionary table in my database.

Now when I use this loader despite of loading of default string loader;in my validation text, it does not show the ${component} label like username/password. It comes like "the field '' is required" where the filed name remains empty. How could I fix this?

I have tried one solution.Here are my codes:

1) I have loader my String loader like this in my Application class:

```
  getResourceSettings().getStringResourceLoaders().add(0,
            new ClassStringResourceLoader(MyApplication.class));

    getResourceSettings().getStringResourceLoaders()
       .add(1, new DictionaryLoader((IDicitureService)
        applicationContext.getBean(IDicitureService.class)));
```

here `DictionaryLoader` is just an implementation of `IStringResourceLoader`.

2) In my login form I have added my username and password field like this:

```
    final FeedbackPanel feedback = new FeedbackPanel("feedback");
    feedback.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    form.add(feedback);
    form.add(new FormComponentFeedbackBorder("username_border")
            .add(new RequiredTextField("username",String.class)
                    .setLabel(new StringResourceModel("COMP:0:0", this, null))));
    form.add(new FormComponentFeedbackBorder("password_border").
            add(new PasswordTextField("password")
                    .setLabel(new StringResourceModel("COMP:1:0", this, null))));
    add(form);
```

where`new StringResourceModel("COMP:1:0", this, null)` just returns a string like username ... password etc.

Now if I check my page it replaces the validator content with my provided text when I use TextField.setLabel() which in fact is for validator label. But I am not using ${label} here.

Is this a good way to do that? Or it can be done in other way.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the values for 'COMP:0:0' and 'COMP:1:0' message keys?

You should use the same syntax as wicket does by default:

```
Required=Field '${label}' is required.
```

${label} is either an actual label (if you set one) or field ID (if you didn't set the label).